Is this an Xcode bug?
The xcode debugger jumps unexpectedly from line 11 to line 16 (past return!) in this C++ code and back to
line 11, when I do "step over" or "step in". (This is the minimal working example, so the silly "for" loop is needed.) Is this a debugger bug?
First:

Second:

And then back to line 11.
Just in case here is the code:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  vector<int> vec={1,2};
  for(int x= 1; x<=1; x++){
  int i=0;
    do{
    int y=vec[i++];
    cout<<i<<endl;
    } while(false);
  }
  return 0;
}

